# Study of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have to study a sequence:$u_n=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{2}{k(1-k)}$ . I have to write it just as a function of n but I can't figure out a way to do so.

Can you please give me a methodology I could apply to this example but also to all the other ones I have to do.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Besides, it wil be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: You need to perform a [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).  Look at Example 1 on the linked page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$u_n=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{2}{k(1-k)}=\\u_n=-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{2}{k(k-1)}=\\
u_n=-\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\frac{2}{k-1}-\frac{2}{k})$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\frac{2}{k(1-k)}=-2\, \left( -1+k \right) ^{-1}+2\,{k}^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) sum:

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{2}{k(1-k)}=-2\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=-2\left(1-\frac 1n \right)$$

Comment: Thanks, I might be missing something obvious but I don't understand how you can go from $\frac{1}{k(1-k)}$ to  $-\frac{1}{k-1} -\frac{1}{k}$